# While screen sharing always getting error from Quickblox Android SDK

Tags: quickblox-android

I have been trying to integrate screen sharing feature but Quickblox SDK is always throwing exception saying **"Start Screen share failed Texture width must be positive, but was 0"**

I have been following their official documentation and followed all the instructions from,

https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/android-video-calling-advanced#screen-sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the size of the screen is specified i.e. following parameters needs to be defined before sharing the screen,

```
QBRTCMediaConfig.setVideoWidth(QBRTCMediaConfig.VideoQuality.VGA_VIDEO.width)
QBRTCMediaConfig.setVideoHeight(QBRTCMediaConfig.VideoQuality.VGA_VIDEO.height)
```